# Always open a txt file using specified app in fish shell

Tags: fish

I use fish shell. I always open `*.txt` files in atom, so I need to type `atom filename.txt`. I know, that in zsh, there's an option to always open files with some extension in the specific app using `alias -s` option. Is there a way to achieve the same behavior in fish shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions come to mind. First, use an abbreviation or function to reduce the number of characters you have to type:

```
abbr a atom
```

Now you can just type "a *.txt". The advantage of doing `function a; atom $argv; end` is that it allows for more complicated steps than just replacing a short command with a longer command. As another example, I have `abbr gcm "git checkout master"` in my config because that's something I do frequently.

Second, use a key binding. For example, arrange for pressing [meta-a] to insert "atom" at the start of the command and execute it:

```
function edit_with_atom
    set -l line (commandline -b)
    commandline -r "atom $line"
    commandline -f execute
end

bind \ea edit_with_atom
```

The key binding allows for more complicated operations than what I've shown above since you can execute arbitrary code.

These solutions don't scale but if there's just a couple of commands you run frequently that you want to invoke with fewer keystrokes they might help.

Comment: I came up with another idea. To write a function with a short name like `a` and depending on the file type argument. For example, if I type `a file.txt`, it executes `atom file.txt`. But if I type `a file.html`, it uses browser to open the file. I'm new to fish shell, that's why it will take time to write things like `$argv` ends with `.txt`, but I think that's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, fish does not support this. Your best bet is to define an ordinary function/alias that calls into atom.